# Kind of discussion forum using HTML 5 on Django

Tags: django, html

I am building a front end using HTML 5 on django framework. Front end shows some posts(like any discussion forum) and I want to allow users to comment on posts. As soon as a user comments, it should be displayed just below the post. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, in order to avoid reinventing the wheel, there are two major options now:

- [django-contrib-comments](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments) (was a part of django till 1.6) (start guide [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/))
- [disqus](http://disqus.com)

Also, take a look at [django-threadedcomments](https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments) package which helps making threading comments.

Hope that helps.